# Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession', connecting to cassandra on docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cassandra

I generated a project on [spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/) with dependencies Web, Cassandra, and Lombok. For now, it's only an empty project, I didn't change anything there. I also have a Cassandra DB set up on docker. Whenever I'm trying to run the project, this is an error that I encounter:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.0)

2020-12-02 08:09:40.325  INFO 7976 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_231 on LAPTOP-AG6Q0BH4 with PID 7976 (C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\demo\target\classes started by Michał in C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\demo)
2020-12-02 08:09:40.330  INFO 7976 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-02 08:09:41.655  INFO 7976 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-12-02 08:09:41.684  INFO 7976 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 13 ms. Found 0 Reactive Cassandra repository interfaces.
2020-12-02 08:09:41.695  INFO 7976 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-12-02 08:09:41.699  INFO 7976 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 2 ms. Found 0 Cassandra repository interfaces.
2020-12-02 08:09:42.491  INFO 7976 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8083 (http)
2020-12-02 08:09:42.503  INFO 7976 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-12-02 08:09:42.503  INFO 7976 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2020-12-02 08:09:42.652  INFO 7976 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-12-02 08:09:42.653  INFO 7976 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2160 ms
2020-12-02 08:09:42.976  INFO 7976 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-12-02 08:09:43.383  INFO 7976 --- [           main] c.d.o.d.internal.core.ContactPoints      : Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2020-12-02 08:09:43.558  INFO 7976 --- [           main] c.d.o.d.i.core.DefaultMavenCoordinates   : DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.9.0
2020-12-02 08:09:44.292  INFO 7976 --- [     s0-admin-0] c.d.oss.driver.internal.core.time.Clock  : Using native clock for microsecond precision
2020-12-02 08:09:48.027  WARN 7976 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter). Current contact points are: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=b5659b)=null, Node(endPoint=localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042, hostId=16e2ee82-a5ad-47d5-9e11-e350bd5f10f5, hashCode=489dc8)=datacenter1. Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1
2020-12-02 08:09:48.029  INFO 7976 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-12-02 08:09:48.033  INFO 7976 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-12-02 08:09:48.048  INFO 7976 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-12-02 08:09:48.079 ERROR 7976 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter). Current contact points are: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=b5659b)=null, Node(endPoint=localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042, hostId=16e2ee82-a5ad-47d5-9e11-e350bd5f10f5, hashCode=489dc8)=datacenter1. Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1206) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter). Current contact points are: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=b5659b)=null, Node(endPoint=localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042, hostId=16e2ee82-a5ad-47d5-9e11-e350bd5f10f5, hashCode=489dc8)=datacenter1. Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter). Current contact points are: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=b5659b)=null, Node(endPoint=localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042, hostId=16e2ee82-a5ad-47d5-9e11-e350bd5f10f5, hashCode=489dc8)=datacenter1. Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter). Current contact points are: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=b5659b)=null, Node(endPoint=localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042, hostId=16e2ee82-a5ad-47d5-9e11-e350bd5f10f5, hashCode=489dc8)=datacenter1. Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.loadbalancing.helper.MandatoryLocalDcHelper.discoverLocalDc(MandatoryLocalDcHelper.java:91) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.loadbalancing.DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy.discoverLocalDc(DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy.java:118) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.loadbalancing.BasicLoadBalancingPolicy.init(BasicLoadBalancingPolicy.java:126) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.loadbalancing.DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy.init(DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy.java:109) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.LoadBalancingPolicyWrapper.init(LoadBalancingPolicyWrapper.java:121) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession$SingleThreaded.afterInitialSchemaRefresh(DefaultSession.java:444) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession$SingleThreaded.lambda$afterInitialNodeListRefresh$5(DefaultSession.java:434) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.MetadataManager$SingleThreaded.lambda$startSchemaRequest$1(MetadataManager.java:443) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:561) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultEventLoop.run(DefaultEventLoop.java:54) ~[netty-transport-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_231]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here's a `application.properties` file which I've been trying to edit to get this to work:

```
server.port=8083

spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=gun_violence_db
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=localhost
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
```

Tried many variations.
And lastly here's a container I'm trying to connect to:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                 NAMES
04da32541575        cassandra:latest    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   29 seconds ago      Up 24 seconds       7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9160/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp             cassandra_db
```

What can cause this issue? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter)`

Comment: Huh, weird, earlier I did specify data center and another issue came up so I thought it's something else, but now it worked just fine. Anyway, thank you.